# VBA - Finding the Next row and Auto-incrementing the Log ID

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Assistance required on this one, its probably something easy but im still developing when it comes to VBA.

I have a userform that is used to update a log of requests, i want it to operate so that it looks down column A to establish the Last row and the Last used reference number. Once the new submission is entered i want it to populate to the next blank row whilst auto incrementing the reference number.  The reference Numbers are formatted as below.

| Column A (RefNo) | Column B LA |
| --- | --- |
| LSI-1 | Data |
| LSI-2 | Data |
| LSI-3 | Data |
| LSI-4 | Data |
| etc.. | Data |

just for reference, due to the logs headers etc, LSI-1 starts on row 6.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.Height = 424
Me.Width = 438
Me.Zoom = 100

Txt_DateLogged.Value = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
Txt_Month.Value = Format(Date, "MMM-YY")

Call CBO_Supplier_Items
Call CBO_SRM_Items
Call CBO_Cause_Items

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LSI Log")


With ws
    i = .Rows.Count
    lstdt = .Range("A" & i).End(xlUp).Value
    Me.Txt_IssueNum.Value = "LSI-" & lstdt + 1
    
    End With
        

End Sub
```

On the userform there is a textbox Txt_IssueNum which is not enabled but i want it to be populated with the new reference number during the userform Initialising.

When i run my code above i get the Error Type Mismatch error message.

Any thoughts where im going wrong with it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't declared `lstdt` i.e. you don't use `Option Explicit` and the variable is declared as a variant. Anyway, you are trying to add 1 to a string e.g. `LSI-10`. Try `... = "LSI-" & CStr(CLng(Right(lstdt, Len(lstdt) - 4)) + 1)`.

Comment: thats done the trick, thank you. ill have to have a go at backwards engineering your resolution.

Comment: Might be better to remove the `LSI-` from the number and find the maximum number.  If you're data gets sorted by another column your last row won't contain the latest number.

Answer (score 1):

Threw this together so might not be the best code for finding the max (end of the day).....

With your data as below (not sorted, different text in there)

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    'Set reference to your data range.
    Dim TheData As Range
    With ws
        Set TheData = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    'Ask for the next ID relevant to LSI- type.
    MsgBox GetNextID(TheData, "LSI-")

End Sub

Public Function GetNextID(MyDataRange As Range, StartText As String) As String
    
    Dim IDCollection As Collection
    Set IDCollection = New Collection
    
    'Put all numbers relevant to the correct type into a collection.
    Dim itm As Variant
    For Each itm In MyDataRange
        If Left(itm, Len(StartText)) = StartText Then
            'Remove the StartText, turn the number into a value.
            IDCollection.Add Val(Replace(itm, StartText, ""))
        End If
    Next itm
    
    'Find the maximum number.
    Dim MaxNum As Long
    For Each itm In IDCollection
        If itm > MaxNum Then MaxNum = itm
    Next itm
    
    'Add the StartText back and return the result.
    GetNextID = StartText & MaxNum + 1
    
End Function
```

Results when looking for "LSI-" and then "AB-":
[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Extract Trailing Integers

**A Test**

- Use this test sub before using the function in your sub.

```vb
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print GetNewId
End Sub
```

**The Function**

- Adjust the first cell `"A2"`.

```vb
Function GetNewId() As String
    
    Const ID_PREFIX As String = "LSI-"
    
    Dim IdNumbers()
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LSI Log")
        Dim EvalString As String
        With .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            EvalString = "Value(Right(" & .Address _
                & ",LEN(" & .Address & ")-" & Len(ID_PREFIX) & "))"
        End With
        IdNumbers = .Evaluate(EvalString)
    End With
    
    Dim IdNumber, MaxNumber As Long
    
    For Each IdNumber In IdNumbers
        If IsNumeric(IdNumber) Then
            If IdNumber > MaxNumber Then MaxNumber = IdNumber
        End If
    Next IdNumber
    
    Dim NewId As String: NewId = ID_PREFIX & CStr(MaxNumber + 1)
    
    GetNewId = NewId

End Function
```

**Your New Sub**

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.Height = 424
    Me.Width = 438
    Me.Zoom = 100
    
    Txt_DateLogged.Value = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    Txt_Month.Value = Format(Date, "MMM-YY")
    
    Call CBO_Supplier_Items
    Call CBO_SRM_Items
    Call CBO_Cause_Items
    
    Me.Txt_IssueNum.Value = GetNewId

End Sub
```